# How to pause the BGE and then resume

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

With the logic setup below I'm trying to pause the game, then on any key stroke resume where it was paused. Trouble is when the BGE is *Paused* it seemingly can't listen for any input.
<sub>click image for full size</sub>
[image: logic bricks]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does appear that a suspended scene does not respond to any events, which sounds right when you think about it.

A solution is to use a second scene to control the play. When starting game play connect a scene actuator that sets a second scene as a scene overlay. This second scene only needs one object, which can be an empty, and contains the pause/resume pieces as you have shown, just with the pause/resume scene set to the first scene not the second that has the pause controls.

If you have setup a scene as an overlay to display scores etc then you can just use one of these objects.